# Android change Action Bar color not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am setting the theme of my app to MyTheme:

```
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#B87333</item>
    </style>
```

but this doesn't seem to be working. I set the application theme to this one. The graphical layout is saying the actionbar is brown, but when I run the app, the color is not brown, but the holo.light style.

Comment: Android version? do you use ABS or ABC ?

Comment: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ generate a style from here.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your MainActivities onCreate:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xFF3F9FE0));
```

replace `0xFF3F9FE0` with your color code. the format is `AARRGGBB`

Comment: @Aashir thanks so much for the answer, but I need to define the color in code.

Comment: @Aashir can you tell me how to fix the xml?